# Excel Int to date in Hive

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hql

I ingested csv table to a Hive table but the date is being shown as integer value. Is there a way to convert Integer value (stored as string) to date in Hive?

[image]

When I do this

```
select cast(day_id2 as date) from table1
```

...I get null values:

[image]

Can someone tell me an elegant way to convert integer values (stored as string) into date values.